# How can I set variables in the Panel shared by Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have created a new dashboard in Grafana. I want to embed the panels in the dashboard into my webpage, but my panel uses some variables. How can I set the values of these variables

[share panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKIR6.png)

I used the share panel feature to share my panel, but I couldn't find a place to set variables

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution
After setting the format of the variable to text, can set the variable value in the sharing link，like: http://$IPADDRESS/grafana/d-solo/a2loud/jixsd?orgId=1&var-**node**=ubuntu-adater&panelId=2, node is my variable